# How to register Javascript function to find when HiddenField value changed?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page that contains a `HiddenField` control, I register some javascript on page load which contains a function I want to run when the HiddenField value has changed.

Currently, I have the following code which executes the function if an input field's value has changed:

```
$(':input').change(function(){ pageHasBeenUpdated = true;  });
```

What javascript would I need to set `pageHasBeenUpdated = true` if the value of the `HiddenField` control has been updated?

Comment: What would update a hiddenField? The answer to your question depends on that.

Comment: The hidden field is updated in the C# code behind. I need to update the line of javascript code to find the value of a hidden field (the javascript runs after $(document).ready()) $(':input').change() works for textbox fields on the page, but it doesn't work for hidden fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the hidden input elements by specifying it in an attribute selector:

```
$('input[type=hidden]')
```

Since the `change` event isn't triggered when you update the value of a hidden input field you'll need to fire it yourself when you update the value of the input.

Example:

**Html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput">
<button id="valueChanger">Change hidden input value</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=hidden]').change(function(){alert($(this).val())});

$('#valueChanger').click(function(){
    $('#myHiddenInput').val("Hello World").trigger('change');
 });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8rT4E/1/)

Comment: What does the ':' mean in $(':input').change? Is it necessary for the code you provided?

Comment: The colon is usually used when using pseudo-selectors such as `$('input:after')`. I'm not sure of it's function preceeding a basic element selector.